# Lengths and for-loops

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, lengths, foreach

It seems that lengths are not updated in for loops.
Compiling the code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newlength{\test}
\newcommand{\inc}{\addtolength{\test}{1cm}}
\newcommand{\incs}{\foreach \x in {1,2,3} {\addtolength{\test}{1cm}}}

\begin{document}

Test: .\hspace{\test}.

\inc

Test: .\hspace{\test}.

\setlength{\test}{0cm}

\incs

Test: .\hspace{\test}.

\end{document}
```

We expect to see

> Test: .. 
>   Test: .--. 
>   Test: .------.

But the last line shows

> Test: ..

It is a bit annoying because I wanted to use a floating point 
number to be remembered in a TikZ picture, each time I call 
a function in a for loop.

---

**EDIT**
I want to write code for a piecewise function.
Here is what I have

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\currX}
\setlength{\currX}{0mm}
\newlength{\currY}
\setlength{\currY}{0mm}
\newcommand{\drawbar}[2]{
  \draw (\currX,\currY) -- (\currX,\currY+{#2}) -- (\currX+{#1},\currY+{#2});
  \global\addtolength{\currX}{#1}
  \global\addtolength{\currY}{#2}
 }
\newcommand{\drawbars}[1]{
  \foreach \x/\y in {#1}{
   \drawbar{\x}{\y}
   }
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \drawbar{2mm}{4mm}
    \drawbar{20mm}{40mm}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \drawbars{2mm/4mm, 20mm/40mm}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I get a compile error:

```
You can't use a prefix with `\begingroup'.
<to be read again> 

\begingroup 

l.23     \drawbar{2mm}{4mm}
```

---

**EDIT2**

The second question turns out to be the same as
[TikZ, foreach and sum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33125/tikz-foreach-and-sum)

Prefixing with global as suggested does not compile in my more specific example above, the solution above does well.

Answer (score 6):

The commands `\addtolength` and related length macro adjusters are designed to behave locally. You can make it global but I'm not sure if that's the good way to go.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newlength{\test}
\newcommand{\inc}{\addtolength{\test}{1cm}}
\newcommand{\incs}[1]{\foreach \x in {1,...,#1} {\global\addtolength{\test}{1cm}} }

\begin{document}
\the\test
\inc

\the\test
\setlength{\test}{0cm}

\the\test

\incs{5}
\the\test

\setlength{\test}{0cm}
\incs{3}
\the\test
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also you can check [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25462/why-do-setcounter-and-addtocounter-commands-have-global-effect-while-setleng) for a similar query.

---

**For Edited Question**

The following works for the edited version of your problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newlength{\currX}\setlength{\currX}{0mm}
\newlength{\currY}\setlength{\currY}{0mm}
\newcommand{\drawbar}[2]{
  \draw (\currX,\currY) -- (\currX,\currY+#2) -- (\currX + #1,\currY+ #2);
    \global\advance \currX by #1
    \global\advance \currY by #2
 }
\newcommand{\drawbars}[1]{\foreach \x/\y in #1{\drawbar{\x}{\y}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0){O};
    \drawbar{2mm}{4mm}
    \drawbar{20mm}{40mm}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0){O};
    \drawbars{{2mm/4mm, 10mm/20mm}}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

with the following output

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I have trouble copy pasting

Comment: @BrunoBauwens Can you put this in your question please for other visitors of the site to make it more informative?

Comment: My question is the same as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33125/tikz-foreach-and-sum 
and the answer works.

Comment: @BrunoBauwens If you describe your problem better it's much easier to reach to the solution. So that we don't duplicate our efforts each time you edit the question. I've changed the dimensions to make it a smaller image.